# gazebo garden, how to set background colour

Tags: gazebo

My current .sdf file looks like the following.
my goal is to set the background to a specific colour by changing this sdf file. Found online "solutions" state that this can be done by setting the background variable in the [scene tag](http://sdformat.org/spec?elem=scene). However I can't see any changes when this is done. The only thing i can think of is maybe its being overridden by some other value, but the verbose output seems fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version='1.9'>
<world name='default'>
    <physics name='1ms' type='ignored'>
    <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
    <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
    <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
    </physics>

    <scene>
      <ambient>0 0 0 0</ambient>
      <background>0 0 0 0</background>
      <shadows>true</shadows>
      <grid>true</grid>
    </scene>



    <light name='sun' type='directional'>
    <pose>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
    <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>
    <intensity>1</intensity>
    <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
    <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
    <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
    <attenuation>
        <range>1000</range>
        <linear>0.01</linear>
        <constant>0.90000000000000002</constant>
        <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
    </attenuation>
    <spot>
        <inner_angle>0</inner_angle>
        <outer_angle>0</outer_angle>
        <falloff>0</falloff>
    </spot>
    </light>

</world>
</sdf>
```

[image: Picture of simulation without correct background colour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the strange (undocumented?) things of Gazebo Sim: there is an element `<background>` in the `<scene>` element in the SDF, but also a `<background_color>` element in the configuration of the `MinimalScene` plugin.

I don't know when the former is used, but the latter does set the background color:

#### To set from the SDF

Have a look at the [empty_gui.sdf](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/empty_gui.sdf) example world:

If you follow [instructions 1. and 2.](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/e007fa2c0b2e795ab1b74c75e48962b8dfacedba/examples/worlds/empty_gui.sdf#L6-L15) you will see that the scene initially loads with background color as specified by the [MinimalScene `<background_color>`](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/e007fa2c0b2e795ab1b74c75e48962b8dfacedba/examples/worlds/empty_gui.sdf#L51). Try changing it: the numbers represent RGB, with value between 0.0 and 1.0.

Upon load of the Scene Manager plugin per instruction 2., the background color is replaced by a sky texture, which can be avoided by removing [this line](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/e007fa2c0b2e795ab1b74c75e48962b8dfacedba/examples/worlds/empty_gui.sdf#L59). So strangely, the `<sky>` setting of the `<scene>` entry *does* have an effect, whereas the [`<background>` setting](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/e007fa2c0b2e795ab1b74c75e48962b8dfacedba/examples/worlds/empty_gui.sdf#L58) does *not*.

#### To set from the gui config file

Alternatively, the same `<background_color>` setting can be done in the gui config file. The default file is located at `${HOME}/.gz/sim/7/gui.config`. A custom config file can be loaded by starting Gazebo Sim with:

`gz sim --gui-config <path_to_config_file>`

The current config can be saved from Gazebo Sim by clicking the horizontal lines icon at the top left and choosing `Save client configuration as`.

#### To set programmatically

If you'd want to change the background color programmatically, take a look at [this tutorial](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/rendering_plugins.html) and corresponding [source code](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/main/examples/plugin/rendering_plugins). Note the difference between the server-side scene (used by Gazebo Sim sensors) and the gui-side scene.